# What are the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}[\sqrt{-3}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let me consider $R=\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}[\sqrt{-3}]$, I want to find all prime ideals in $R$.

I know that we have given an inclusion $$\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\rightarrow R$$ by $$\frac{a}{b}\mapsto \frac{a}{b}\sqrt{-3}$$where $2$ does not divide $b$ right?
What I also could show is that a preimage of a prime ideal under a homomorphism is again a prime ideal. So if I take $I\subset R$ a prime ideal. What can I say about this? Our prof. gave us the hint during the lecture that $I\cap \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}\in \{0,(2)\}$ but I don't see why this should be true.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The inclusion is given by $\frac ab\mapsto \frac ab$...

Comment: @Arthur ah okey but I still do not see why the hint should be true then?

Comment: Do you know what the prime ideals of $\Bbb Z_{(2)}$ are?

Comment: @Arthur the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$ are in one to one correspondence with the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ disjoint from $\Bbb{Z}\setminus (2)$. But the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ are $(0)$ and $(p)$ for $p$ prime. Then clearly $(0)\cap \Bbb{Z}\setminus (2)=\emptyset$ and $(p)\cap \Bbb{Z}\setminus (2)=\emptyset $ iff $(p)=(2)$. So the prime ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$ are $(0)\cdot \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$ and $(2)\cdot \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$. Right?

Comment: @Arthur and then $(0)\cdot \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}=(0)$ and $(2) \cdot \Bbb{Z}_{(2)}=(2)$ right?

Comment: Looks good. And given a ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$ (like, for instance, your inclusion homomorphism $\Bbb Z_{(2)}\to R$), what do you know about the sets $f^{-1}(p)\subseteq A$ for prime ideals $p\subseteq  B$?

Comment: @Arthur so I know that the preimage of a prime ideal in $B$ is again a prime ideal in $A$

Comment: @Arthur But with the knowledge that the prime ideals in $\Bbb{Z}_{(2)}$ are $(0),(2)$ we have that $f^{-1}(p)\in \{(0),(2)\}$

Comment: And that's exactly why the given hint is true. The given intersection is the inverse map of the inclusion map.

Comment: @Arthur Ah okey I see thank you